# Improving the JQuery MP3 Player Plugin code

Tags: jquery

I am not the most experienced jquery author and I came up with a solution to a simple problem, but to me it doesn't seem like the best way to do it. I think the code explains it best:

```
$("#play_button").click( function () {
    $("#play_button").hide();
    $("#pause_button").show();
});

$("#pause_button").click( function () {
    $("#play_button").show();
    $("#pause_button").hide();
});
```

Any suggestions on a better block of code to accomplish the same thing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming one starts visible, and the other doesn't:

```
$("#pause_button, #play_button").click(function(){
  $("#play_button, #pause_button").toggle();
});
```

Online demo: http://jsbin.com/ewave/edit

If you apply a simple class to both: `class='button'`, you can make it even simpler:

```
$(".button").click(function(){
  $(".button").toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on Jonathan's answer, I kinda like this, but it's less explicit:

```
var buttons = $('#play_button, #pause_button');
buttons.click($.proxy(buttons, 'toggle'));
```

It does, though, offer the advantage of not having to repeat yourself when it comes to naming the buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine, but I would at least do this:

```
$("#play_button").click( function () {
    $(this).hide();
    $("#pause_button").show();
});

$("#pause_button").click( function () {
    $(this).hide();
    $("#play_button").show();
});
```

Using $(this) adds clarity, IMHO.

Johnathan Sampson's solution is also good, if you prefer that.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Jonathan's answer except i would use a catchall id an then change the class...

pseudo html

```
<element id="player_button" class="play">
</element>
```

css:

```
#player_button { /* general style rules like position dimensions cursor */}
#player_button.play {/* play button bg image */}
#player_button.pause {/* pause button bg image */}
```

js:

```
$('$player_button').click(function(){
   var button = $(this);
   if(button.is('.play'){
      // logic to initiate play
   }
   if(button.is('.pause')){
      // logic to initiate pause
   }

   button.toggleClass('pause').toggleClass('play');
});
```

Ofcourse if youre using 1.4 you can supply a function to toggleClass to detect which classes should be added/removed. This is sut preference to not have two separate elements in the DOM unless it makes functional sense.